# This python 3 infix notation fails, and I can't see why

Tags: python, python-3.x, infix-notation, category-theory

I was trying to code some category theory.  One requirement is associativity, so "(ab)c = a(bc)" Trying to code that with the infix module, I found my version of the right-hand side ("a(bc)") did not run right.  Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

---

```
import infix #from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/infix/  #Thanks for the module!
from infix import or_infix

# Uses the "or" sign | around infix functions, eg "then(a,b)" becomes "a |then| b"
# Function "then(a,b)" also works and I use it first in the test below
@or_infix 
def then(f,g):
    '''returns a function that = g(f())'''
    #assertion tests make sure arguments are functions, ie that they can be called.
    assert callable(f)
    assert callable(g)
    def h(x):
        return g(f(x))
    return h


def m5(x):
    print("m5 is subtracting 5")
    return x-5

def p5(x):
    print("p5 is adding 5")
    return x+5

def double(x):
    print ("double is multiplying by 2")
    return 2*x

x = 0
print ("Setting the arg x to 0")


print("Using function language:")
print( then(m5,then(p5, double))(x) ) #This works and gives 0
print()
print("|then| with abbreviations:") 
pd = p5 |then| double
print((m5 |then| pd)(x)) #This works and gives 0
print()
print("Straight-through with |then|")  
print((m5 |then| p5 |then| double)(x)) #This works and gives 0
print()
print("Using |then| language with parentheses:") 
print( (m5 |then| (p5 |then| double ))(x) ) #The problem code
#This last does not work. p5 runs twice, m5 not at all.  Why, though?
```

Comment: Sanity check: are you sure you didn't just accidentally write `p5` instead of `m5` on the last line when you were testing this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  When I run the given code in Python 3.5.2 with infix 1.2, the last test outputs `Using |then| language with parentheses:␊m5 is subtracting 5␊p5 is adding 5␊double is multiplying by 2␊0`

Comment: If your report is accurate, I suspect the problem is due to `infix` clobbering its `_function` attribute with `update_wrapper`. I don't have an `infix` install I can test on at the moment.

Comment: Thank you to @user2357112 for the suggestion that infix might be doing the clobbering.  (And also for the sanity check - but I did have the right m5 instead of p5.)

Comment: And thanks to @jwodder for mentioning infix 1.2.  I had been running infix 1.0.  I found infix1.2 and pipped it aboard, and now the program runs correctly.